# Forbidden You don't have permission to access /appetitclic/wp-content/themes/Apc/img/logo.png on this server

Tags: image, wordpress, wamp

**Hello all :)**

I am currently working on a WP website and a the moment I am working locally with Wampserver.
None of my pictures happen to appear on my website.

Here is the error I get when I put the image url in my browser :

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access
>   /appetitclic/wp-content/themes/Apc/img/logo.png on this server.

I have no problem accessing phpmyadmin and image from TewentyTwelve template work fine.

Things I have tried :

```
-Editing (and creating) .htaccess in wp-admin.
-Editing phpmyadmin.conf
-Puting Wamp on online mode
-Working through http://127.0.0.1/ instead of locally.
```

I am pretty sure the problem doesn't have to so with the code because I have access to the /appetitclic/wp-content/themes/Apc/img/ folder and I see the list of images (not working). I maybe missed one or two workarounds but I am pretty sure I tried most of the common ones.

If you need any info on my setup / configs I have tried ask away.

Thank you very much,
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you start your relative url with a backslash '/' that means go to the servers root folder and work up from there.

Try loosing the leading slash and see what that does.

Answer (score 0):

I have that same problem when I downloaded random images for img preloading testing.
So I went to change permission from no access to read & write (if on Mac then > Get info. You shall see that permission section at the very bottom).
You might use chmod to change permission to particular users.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. I created a static webpage put in the html folder of my web server. It turned out that some images could not be loaded. The solution is quite simple. I just right click the image folder and changed the properties to allow readers to view the images.